# Dynamic input table to dynamic label table in HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, rows

I am trying to make this function I used in my program before but instead of having input fields showing the data, I need it to show labels or text with the data so I can copy and paste it in Excel.

Here is the method:

```
    cnt=0;
function addRowReporte(tableID,nroColumna) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(c=0;c<nroColumna;c++){

        var cell = row.insertCell(c);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";

        element.name = ct+"0"+c;
        element.size = "16";
        element.id = ct+"0"+c;

        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

I tried changing the `createElement("input")` to label but it didn't work

The text or "value" of the field is later on called using this:

```
document.getElementById(id).value = rs.Fields(colu).Value;
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As a start, could you provide a nonworking example using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @RickViscomi what do u mean by a non working example? The example is working but I am populating it using a SQL query in a RecordSet and is too much code to post here or to create a jsfiddle example. I just want a short example on how to change each "input" cell to like a label cell where I can edit the value. Is that better?

Comment: What text do you want to add to the table cells?

Comment: @randomizertech I just mean show us what you're trying to do and how it's broken. Then we can tell you why it won't work and how to fix it. You don't need to copy your exact use case, just a short example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RickViscomi ok, I tried doing it in jsFiddle but it didn't work for some reason so I found this example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement2 Right now I have something like that but changing createElement("BUTTON") for INPUT and I need to make it work changing it to LABEL and then assign some sort of value to it from another function but getElementById(id) is not working with the element LABEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text nodes to insert text directly into the table cells, like so...

```
cnt=0;
function addRowReporte(tableID,nroColumna) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(c=0;c<nroColumna;c++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(c);
        var element = document.createTextNode("text goes here");

        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw this in another post too, but when I try to populate the table it does not work. See update to see how I give a value to the input field. It works perfectly fine with <input /> but not with label :(

Comment: I tried document.getElementById(id).createTextNode(rs.Fields(colu).Value); but it gave me an error saying Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: If you want to update the value of an existing cell, you would use document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'whatever';

Comment: I tried that too, element.innerHTML = "<label id=101></label>" but I cannot assign a value to it from another function like I need to

Comment: Ok I get what you said. I ended up with document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<label> "+rs.Fields(colu).Value+"</label>"; and it worked fine. Do you know how I can edit the size of the label?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using labels, but you can set the width of the table cell like so... cell.style.width = "200px";